# angularjs and googles url shortener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-url-shortener

I have an issue at the moment with the google url shortener.
I have set up this service:

```
angular.module('widget.core').service('urlShortener', service);

function service($log, $q, $http) {

    var gapiKey = '<MyApiKey>';
    var gapiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url';

    return {
        shorten: shorten
    };

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function shorten(url) {
        console.log(url);
        var data = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: gapiUrl + '?key=' + gapiKey,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            data: {
                longUrl: url,
            }
        };

        return $http(data).then(function (response) {
            $log.debug(response);
            return response.data;
        }, function (response) {
            $log.debug(response);
            return response.data;
        });
    };
};
```

As far as I can tell, this should work. I have put in the correct API key and when I run this method I get this error:

```
{
    error: {
        code: 401,
        message: 'Invalid credentials'
    }
}
```

But, if I use postman and set it up exactly like this method:

- Make it post
- Add the content-type header and set it to application/json
- set the url to **https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=myapikey**
- set the body to:

  {
      longUrl: 'myreallylogurl.com'
  }

When I post this, it works with no issues.
I have checked my application on the google console and it is definitely set to unrestricted.

Has anyone come across this issue before? Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, it was nothing to do with the code above, but I thought I would answer my own question because someone else may run into the same issue.

In the project I have an **httpInterceptor** set up that adds the authetentication token to each request for talking to my API. This was what was causing the issue.
It so happened that I already defined a constant for my **apiUrl**, so I just updated the interceptor to check to make sure that the request url was my api before trying to append the token.
Like this:

```
angular.module('widget.core').factory('authInterceptor', factory);

function factory($q, $location, $localStorage, apiUrl) {

    // The request function
    var request = function (config) {

        // If we are querying our API
        if (config.url.indexOf(apiUrl) > -1) {

            // Get our stored auth data
            var authData = angular.fromJson($localStorage.get('authorizationData'));

            // Set our headers to the request headers or a new object
            config.headers = config.headers || {};

            // If we have any auth data
            if (authData && authData.authenticated) {

                // Set our authorization header
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
            }
        }

        // Return our config
        return config;
    };

    return {
        request: request
    };
};
```

I hope that helps someone else. Took me hours to figure it out :/